# Why is that slicing expression generating that output

Tags: python, slice

I got this:

```
#slicing: [start:end:step]
s = 'I am not the Messiah'
#s[0::-1] = 'I'
```

So in this case

```
start=0, end=0, step=-1
```

Why is

```
s[0::-1] == 'I'
>>>> True
```

Comment: The `end` is not `0` it is `None` so it defaults to `s[0:-len(s)-1:-1]` or `s[0:-21:-1]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm not sure if it is a relevant dupe here. I mean it explain the mechanics behind it, but I admit it can still be confusing for someone looking at how the parameters are named.

Comment: @scharette I think the dupe is correct but I've added in a more generic duplicate too in case they need a more basic explanation of slicing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, `-1` is a reversed stepping in this case.

Therefore when you say

```
s[0::-1]
```

You're actually going backward from position `0` to `-1` **where `0` is included**

Therefore, returning `I` in your case.

Note that when I say position `0` to `-1` I mean that it will include position 0 and stop slicing after since a `-1` index is not valid (which is different from reversed indexing like `my_list[-1]`)

Answer (score 1):

Because your slice starts with index 0 and steps -1 at a time, which means it hits the boundary immediately, leaving just the first item in the sequence, i.e. `'I'`, in the slice.